# Whitch gc strat shoud I use if I want to clean up a memory between operations and the time doesn't matter?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a specific question. I have a program what is make searching in big datasets. I have a cache in the searcher to make the program faster. This cache is a big hashmap what contains hashmaps.
My main function is create a searcher to a dataset, get the searching params, do the search, write it down and then make a new searcher to an other dataset and make the searching again.

I give the VM 4gb memory, one cache take about 1,5gb. So the first and second search go smoothli and full speed, but in the third search the gc start trashing and eats the cpu time.

In code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Searchvals sv=new Searchvals("c:\\svs.txt")
  Searcher s=new Searcher("d:\\");
  s.init();
  s.makeSearch(sv);
  s.writeOut("c:\\out1.txt");
  System.gc();

  s=new Searcher("e:\\");
  s.init();
  s.makeSearch(sv);
  s.writeOut("c:\\out2.txt");
  System.gc();

  s=new Searcher("f:\\");
  s.init();
  s.makeSearch(sv);
  s.writeOut("c:\\out3.txt");
}
```

So I'm searching the gc strategy whitch makes a big clean if I call it, or if the memory is running low. The time is not matters, its not a responsible application, its a data miner, after each processes I want to free all the memory what is passible.

I'm tryed to google it but it's not an easy topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `System.gc()` when there is no garbage (the searcher is live and its cache is full).

You should assign `s=null;` or if it doesn't consume a lot of memory `s=new Searcher("e:\\");` before calling `System.gc()`.

Dismantling the cache data structure (`HashMap.clear()` etc.) is another option, in case you want to reuse your `Searcher`.

Are you sure you don't have nasty static variables or references to your `Searcher` or parts of it?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to improve this much by changing the GC strategy. As your working set is too big compared with the amount of heap you've given the application. I assume your cache is filled up + some memory for other objects/threads/services etc. And I'm also assuming that you didn't write your own cache, and you're using a respectable framework.

You might have 2 options

1. Use an off heap cache (such as [Apache Direct Memory](http://directmemory.apache.org/)). The GC time depends on the size of the working set, which in your case is 1.5GB+ (I assume your cache gets filled up pretty soon).
2. Reduce the size of the cache to 1GB and try again.